# Difficulties with this integral

Tags: calculus, analysis

I have to calculate the integral $\int\sqrt{1+\cos^2x}dx$ and I do not know how to proceed!

I tried to solve the differential equation associated: $y'=\sqrt{1+\cos^2x}$ then $y''=\frac{-\sin x\cos x}{y'}$. So if $z=\frac{y}{y'}$ then 
$$z'=1+\frac{\sin x\cos x}{1+\cos^2x}z$$
The solutions of the homogeneous equation are of the form : $z_h=\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2x}}$, but it's difficult to find a particular solution! (variation of the constant gives $\lambda'=\sqrt{1+\cos^2x}$!).

I tried to write, since $t\mapsto\sqrt{1+\cos^2t}$ is $\pi$-periodic and even: $$y=\int_0^x\sqrt{1+\cos^2t}dt=2E(x)\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1+\cos^2t}dt+\int_{E(x)}^x\sqrt{1+\cos^2t}dt...$$
I tried the following: $\sqrt{1+\cos^2t}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{3+\cos(2t)}$ and with $x=\tan t$
$$\int\sqrt{1+\cos^2x}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\sqrt{3+\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}\times\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx...$$
I thank you for any help!

Comment: wolfram's answer is : integral sqrt(1+cos^2(x)) dx = sqrt(2) E(x|1/2)+constant                                                 http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%28sqrt%281%2Bcos^2%28x%29%29%29

Comment: read about The Weierstrass Substitution. There's a good article at http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/WeierstrassSubstitution.shtml

Comment: Many thanks Hamid for the nice answer. Thanks John-Joy, but the Weierstrass Substitution is not relevant here, because the function is not rational...